# How this hashCode method works?

Tags: java, oop, hashcode

So I did not fully understand how hashCode Overridng Works, so I searched for a tutorial on a hashCode Overriding. I found a tutorial where I learned the concept of a hashCode, same object must have same hashCode( but that does not mean that different objects must have diffrent hashCode). What I did not understand is his implementation of the hashcode:

```
@Override
public int hashCode() {
    int hash = 7;
    hash = 31 * hash + Objects.hashCode(this.myShirtColor);
    return hash;
}
```

What i do not understand here is what will **Objects.hashCode(this.myShirtColor)** give? 
myShirtColor is a String.

Comment: Can you post the link? I think what the writer was simply showing a way to override the default implementation of hashCode by taking the original hashCode and then adding a value to it.

Comment: [`Objects.hashCode`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Objects.html#hashCode(java.lang.Object))

Comment: Of course, http://www.deegeu.com/overriding-equals-and-hashcode-in-java/

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Ok first you need to understand two things **String immutability** and **String Pool**.

**String immutability**

> it means that the content of the String Object can't be changed, once
>   it is created.

**String Pool**

> The Java string constant pool is an area in heap memory where Java
>   stores literal string values. The heap is an area of memory used for
>   run-time operations. When a new variable is created and given a value,
>   Java checks to see if that exact value exists in the pool.

Let's sum up both together in a sample , assuming `String strOne="abc";` the `abc` value is created once (*String Immutability*) and stored on the string pool in heap (*String Pool*), Ok so what if I do another string `String strTwo= "abc";` on the same JVM the compiler will check the pool if it `abc` is exist which is true then it is retrieved.

That means: `strOne == strTwo` is `true` since both refer to the same object

Ok back to hashcode you can see now if 2 object on your case has the same 
`shirtColor` will have the same hashcode

if `shirtColor="blue"` for example
Then right after you have an object e.g `shirt1` of your class -you did not mention- but assuming `Shirt` class a `blue` value string is stored in heap if you created another object of class `Shirt` with color `"blue"` e.g `shirt2`, the `blue` value will be fetched from string pool the very exact same object as `shirt1`'s `shirtColor` if you then called the `hashCode` for both objects it will be the same since it depends on the very exact object `"blue"`.

`Objects.hashCode` is a simple function that does check object if null returns 0 otherwise returns object's hashCode

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Objects.html#hashCode(java.lang.Object)

Comment: Thank you! I searched for algohitm for String hashCode and i found this:
s[0]*31^(n - 1) + s[1]*31^(n - 2) + ... + s[n - 1], is s[0] , s[1] ascii values of those charachters? and what s represents, i Know it is a string but how can we multiply a String with an Integer.

Comment: What are you trying to do? If you need to design a hashcode you pick any number of instance variable(s) from your class and use it in the hashCode function if the instance variable is an object such as String just call its builtin hashcode function otherwise if it is primitive use as it is.